# Cannot get state in Hyperledger fabric correctly?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

**Problem:**

I have developed a Hyperledger fabric network and after that, I install a chain code in there. This is my Initialize ledger methods looks like.

```
async initLedger(stub, args) {
    console.info("============= START : Initialize Ledger ===========");
    let drivers = [];

    drivers.push({
      nic: "123",
      firstName: "Saman",
      lastName: "Frenando",
      status: "Not verified",
      licenceNo: "1234"
    });

    drivers.push({
      nic: "124",
      firstName: "Janith",
      lastName: "Bentharaarachchi",
      status: "Not verified",
      licenceNo: "1235"
    });


    for (let i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {
      drivers[i].docType = "driver";
      console.log(drivers[i].nic); 
      await stub.putState(
        drivers[i].nic,
        Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(drivers[i]))
      );
      console.info("Added <--> ", drivers[i]);
    }

 console.info("============= END : Initialize Ledger ===========");
  }
```

This is how I am retrieving those data.

```
async selectNthDriver(stub, args) {
    if (args.length != 1)  {
      throw new Error(
        "Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting NIC ex: 123"
      );
    }
    let nic = args[0];
    console.log(`nic: ${nic}`);

    let driverAsBytes = await stub.getState(nic); 
    console.log("hi"+driverAsBytes);
    if (!driverAsBytes || driverAsBytes.toString().length <= 0) {
      throw new Error("Driver with NIC" + nic + " does not exist");
    }
    console.log(driverAsBytes.toString());
    return driverAsBytes;
  }
```

When I am Issuing this command on peer it successfully initializes the ledger.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n mycc -c '{"Args":["initLedger"]}'
```

By Issuing the following command when I try to retrieve a driver it leaves me an error by saying this.

> Error: endorsement failure during invoke. response: status:500 message:"transaction returned with failure: Error: Driver with NIC123 does not exist"

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C myc -n mycc -c '{"Args":["selectNthDriver","123"]}
```

This is the chaincode logs.

> 2019-05-09T05:18:51.184Z info [lib/handler.js]
>   info: [myc-09f261c4] Calling chaincode Init() succeeded.
>   Sending COMPLETED message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-09T05:18:51.184Z"} { fcn: 'initLedger', params:
>   [] }
>   ============= START : Initialize Ledger =========== 123 Added <-->  { nic: '123',   firstName: 'Saman',   lastName: 'Fernando',   status:
>   'Not verified',   licenceNo: '1234',   docType: 'driver' } 124 Added
>   <-->  { nic: '124',   firstName: 'Janith',   lastName:
>   'Bentharaarachchi',   status: 'Not verified',   licenceNo: '1235',
>   docType: 'driver' }
>   ============= END : Initialize Ledger =========== { fcn: 'selectNthDriver', params: [ '123' ] } nic: 123 hi
>   Error: Driver with NIC123 does not exist
>       at selectNthDriver (/usr/local/src/mycc.js:494:13)
>       at 
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7) 2019-05-09T05:43:42.430Z error [lib/handler.js]
>   error: [myc-e7aef847] Calling chaincode Invoke() returned
>   error response [Error: Driver with NIC123 does not exist].
>   Sending ERROR message back to peer
>   {"timestamp":"2019-05-09T05:43:42.430Z"}

And when I go to the CouchDB through browser It is not showing the data I initialized. It only shows this data.

```
{
  "_id": "mycc",
  "_rev": "1-5c5ecfec35f65ec74cbe52a52be96048",
  "~version": "\u0000CgMBBwA=",
  "_attachments": {
    "valueBytes": {
      "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
      "revpos": 1,
      "digest": "md5-SkPMcpW++nrvo5v00rCdRQ==",
      "length": 424,
      "stub": true
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me to find where am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use "**query**" command for querying a state from the ledger using the peer binary, the invoke command which you have used is for generating a transaction, which is not required for a query operation.

You should just try replacing invoke with query and it should look something like this:

```
peer chaincode query -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C myc -n mycc -c '{"Args":["selectNthDriver","123"]}
```

**EDIT:** Also please check for the following condition in your if statement in the selectNthDriver Method:

```
if (!driverAsBytes.toString())
```

Also please console for the same(driverAsBytes.toString()) in the line just before this if statement in your code.

Comment: Please check the new edit and please post the chaincode logs for the same